# Two fields in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I link two input fields with jQuery autocomplete plugin? For example, I have two fields: City and Street. So when I choose a certain city I want to see in the Street fields just the streets of selected city.

Comment: city and street fields are in one form

Answer (score 0):

I would have the street autocomplete data source submit the value of the city field as a parameter to the street data source.

My jquery call would grab the value from city_field:

```
$(function () {  
    $('#street_field').autocomplete({source: '/autocomplete/street?city="' + $(this).siblings('input[id=city_field]').val() + '"'});
});
```

And in my autocomplete controller (what serves up all my autocomplete data):

```
class AutocompleteController < ApplicationController
  def street
    if params[:term]
      like= "%".concat(params[:term].concat("%"))
      streets = Street.where("city like ? and name like ?", params[:city], like)
    else
      streets = Street.where("city like ?", params[:city])
    end
    list = streets.map {|u| Hash[ id: u.id, label: u.name, name: u.name]}
    render json: list
  end
end
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, post some example code to help us get a better idea of what you are thinking.